# How to deal with conflicting names of two shared libraries?

Tags: shared-library, linker

On my Linux Mint 17.3 system, I installed the packages `libglfw2` and `libglfw-dev`. Since GLFW v3 is not available in repositories, I chose to compile it manually using instructions [here](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/compile.html).

Almost all the instructions I found online state that to link to GLFW v2, I should use `-lglfw` while for GLFW v3, it should be `-lglfw3`. However, doing `-lglfw3` gave the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglfw3
```

while using `-lglfw` gave lots of errors like:

```
1.cpp:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to <function_name>
```

Just to be sure, all the paths in C_INCLUDE_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH were correct. However, after uninstalling the GLFW v2 packaged I had installed using `apt-get` and running `ldconfig`, `-lglfw` worked without a problem. Seems that, somewhere in the CMake file (I guess), there is a bug resulting in name conflict.

My question is: If I have two sources that provide the shared libraries with same name, and if I need them both, what can I do (short of diving in the build config) to workaround the issue? Can I manually change the names of `so` files reliably?

Comment: Where exactly did you install the glfw3 library to? I'm not sure that LD_LIBRARY_PATH is involved in the resolution of build-time library paths (only dynamic runtime libraries)

Comment: The file libglfw.so.3.1 (along with it's links libglfw.so.3 and libglfw.so) is at /usr/local/lib/. Also, since this file's entry is in ld.so.cache (generated by ldconfig), I though adding this path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH might solve the problem.

Comment: This [so] answer looks like it might be helpful [cmake - Linking To A Specific Library](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26169856/4440445)

Comment: The CMake installation worked with no problems- this issue manifests when I try to compile a OpenGL application by linking GLFW.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were *using* `cmake` to build your project - if you are using plain `make` or manually compiling/linking using `gcc` then it should be down to linker directives like `-L /usr/local/lib -lglfw` to ensure the correct library is located first. Did the glfw3 installation provide a `.pc` file and if so are you using `pkg-config`?

Comment: It seems rather surprising that libglfw3 is not available in Mint 17.3, seeing as it is available on Debian jessie. In any case, you should be able to obtain it from the compatible Ubuntu 14.04 repos. See https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glfw3 for example.

Comment: @Faheem Mitha In the above packages too, the .so file is named libglfw.so. I guess that means in this cse, the libraries are backward-compatible. But I'll be interested in general purpose techniques for these kinds of clashes (in case two different libraries have same name).

Comment: @NamanDixit It is possible to install `libglfw-dev`, `libglfw2`, and `libglfw3` together. However, installing `libglfw3-dev` removes `libglfw-dev`. This is on Debian, at least.

Comment: @FaheemMitha The same behaviour is observed in Mint too

Comment: @NamanDixit Do you need to work around this? Note that this means that the two libraries can be co-installed, it's just that you can't compile against both without switching the development package.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Yes, that is exactly what I am asking in the question- a way to keep both libraries with the ability to compile against any one of them depending on the code.

Comment: This sounds like a conversation you could have with the maintainers: Debian Games Team <pkg-games-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>.

Comment: @FaheemMitha No, I am not asking about this particular library. I am asking the general approach to follow when two different libraries with (potentially) different function but same name exist on a system. How to compile against either one of them letting the compiler know which one I want? Or how to rename them so that the problem solves itself?

Comment: @NamanDixit Actually, these libraries do have different names corresponding to their different versions, `lglfw3` and `lglfw3`, so having the option to link against either of them without switching packages should certainly be possible. I don't know why the maintainers made the choice to have this not be possible in this case. Examples where it is possible certainly exist. An obvious example is different versions of g++ and their associated libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Shared libraries are called e.g. `libfoo.so-x.y.z`, with the idea being that `z` gets incremented for minor (totally backwards compatible) changes, `y` is incremented for API additions that keep backward compatibility, while changes to `x` are reserved for major API changes (not compatible). The executable program (check e.g `ldd(1)`'s output for an executable) tells you what library the program requests, by major number (`libfoo.so.x`) and which libary is used to fullfill that dependency (`libfo.so.x.y.z`). The "links against `libfoo.so.x`" is fixed at build time, the exact `y.z` at startup. Thus you can change `y` and/or `z` and have programs still working, and have e.g. `libfoo.so.3` and `libfoo.so.4` installed at the same time, with some programs using one or the others without conflicts.

If you look at the directories for libraries, you will see a chain of symbolic links like `libfoo.so -> libfoo.so.x -> libfoo.so.x.y.z`; when linking with `-lfoo` the linker will follow this and add `libfoo.so.x` as dependency to the executable, and use `libfoo.so.x.y.z` to resolve symbols.

This machinery is tailored to always get the latest `libfoo` when compiling, while having older versions around for legacy applications. Thus often you will see e.g. `libbar.so` and `libbar3.so` (and their farm of symlinks) to be able to build against version 2 (`-lbar`, if the unnumbered legacy version is 2) or 3 (`-lbar3`).

The build machinery *should* be able to sort this out, but it is rather tricky (and not everybody is thrilled by the idea that their latest and shiniest version 3 will stand beside hoary version 2).

Your best bet is to rely on your distribution to set up this mess for you.